# How do I select all selected checkboxes in the NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have NSOutlineView with checkboxes:

[image]

When I select multiple rows they become blue, however if I check any checkbox, I only select the related item (and its children).

[image]

Instead, I would like to check all selected items in the table.

Thanks

Comment: Does anybody know the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

1. Create an action in your view controller to handle the new behavior.
2. Connect your `NSButtonCell`'s action selector to this action.
3. In the new action, you need to propagate the cell's value to the rest of the selected rows. Call `-numberOfSelectedRows` on your outline view to find out if there are any more rows you need to act on, and `-selectedRowIndexes` to get access to the row indexes.
4. After you make the changes to the fields in the model, depending on how your outline view gets its data, you may need to call `-reloadData` to update the display of the other rows.

Comment: Thanks. I've created a new IBAction and wired it from the NSButtonCell in my NSOutlineView. However when I check/uncheck the cell of any row, the action is not triggered. I'm pretty sure the xib file is loaded correctly. I've cleaned and rebuilt after the xib change. What could be wrong ?

Comment: Strange, it sounds like you've done everything right. Before I posted I actually tested this on an `NSTableView` and it worked. I suppose it's possible an outline view gives different behavior. In my test example the action target was the table view's delegate. Try setting that, too?

Comment: Ya I've also tried with a NSTableView in my app, and it doesn't work. I don't think the delegate has anything to do with the IBActions. Other IBActions work in the same xib file. I really don't know anymore what to do :(

Comment: I just tested connecting the button cell selector to the file owner in another nib and it worked right off the bat. I think there's something more basic going on. Would you post the code from your controller class, indicate how you've wired up the action, and explain how your nib is being loaded?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why the IBAction is never called But I've solved differently. This delegate method was implemented in the code: - (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item. And I noticed t is invoked every time I check a box.